# How to make button transparent, but text not?

Tags: c#, xaml

So i want to make my control transparent, but text in it not transparent.
Is there any way it can be done?
I set opacity via Border control, and it now applies to everything in it.

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Height="180"
                    Margin="10,31,0,0"

                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="436"
                    Background="#007aa5"
                    Opacity="0.6">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Height="180"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="TextBlock"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Width="436" 
                       Name="text"/>
            </Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to make only the background brush transparent:

```
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#007aa5" Opacity="0.6"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```